# Finding the most divisible number in a 100,000 range

Tags: c++, performance, numbers

I'm a student in the 10th grade and our teacher assigned some exercises. I'm pretty advanced in my class but one exercise is just isn't coming together as I want. The exercise is as follows:

> Given the numbers between 100,000 and 200,000, find the number with the most divisors (as in which number can be divided with the most numbers, **any** number).

I wrote something but it executes in **32 seconds(!)** and I just can't figure out the logic behind it (I can't even check if the answer is correct).

This is the code that I wrote:

```cpp
void f3() {
    int mostcount = 0, most, divisors = 0;
    for (int i = 100000; i <= 200000; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j<=i/2; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                divisors++;
            }
        }
        if (divisors > mostcount) {
            mostcount = divisors;
            most = i;
        }
        divisors = 0;
    }
    cout << most << endl;
    return;
}
```

The output:

> 166320

Edit: My question is how can I reduce the runtime?

I'd be really thankful if you could explain your answer if you do decide to help, instead of just saying that I could do this with an XYZ type binary tree.

Comment: If you want to speed it up, think in terms of: 1. building a table of primes from 2 to 200000, 2. checking what exponents you can put on them so that it's between the bounds. (3. understand how many divisors a prime factorization means)

Comment: It's not clear what your ask is--why is your algorithm slow? How to test and verify your solution? Is there a faster algorithm?

Comment: replace `j<=i/2` with `j<=sqrt(i)`, you only need to loop up to that, also `#include <math.h>` at the top, you also need to multiply the total divisors by 2, since there is a number above the sqrt that reflects the number below the sqrt. ie: 1000 is 10 x 100.

Comment: @AhmedAEK That seems to have resolved the problem and I've learned something new. I would mark this correct but I'm not sure how to. Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure you have the rep, but you can answer your own question, and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @AhmedAEK 's response:

> replace `j<=i/2` with `j<=sqrt(i)`, you only need to loop up to that, also `#include <math.h>` at the top, you also need to multiply the total divisors by 2, since there is a number above the sqrt that reflects the number below the sqrt. ie: 1000 is 10 x 100.

```cpp
void f3() {
    int mostcount = 0, most, divisors = 0;
    for (int i = 100000; i <= 200000; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j<=sqrt(i); j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                divisors++;
            }
        }
        if (divisors > mostcount) {
            mostcount = divisors;
            most = i;
        }
        divisors = 0;
    }
    cout << most << endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: In C++, include `cmath` instead. Also, it's not the square root that you want to multiply by two, it's the number divisors. However, it doesn't matter since you only want to find the number with the largest number of divisors, and not that number of divisors. Plus it would break for perfect squares, though I don't think a perfect square can be the answer unless the range is tiny.

Comment: as pointed by Nelfeal, remove the `*2`, it's not relevent and your code is faster without it.

Comment: @Nelfeal I've since noticed as I was writing it in a rush and got excited because it worked, but it seems I'm not able to edit my own answer:/

Comment: Figured it out, thanks for teaching me the ways of stackoverflow haha

Comment: A minor issue: You start your inner loop with `j = 1`, so you check every single number if it is divisible by 1.   Rather start with `j = 2` to skip this unecessary check.

Comment: Have this solved your problem? If so please accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this with `performance`...

You can find all the prime factors of your input value (and the number of times they occur), and calculate the number of ALL divisors by multiplying those counts+1. This example cut the time by almost 5 times!

```
void f() {
    int mostcount = 0, most = 0;
    for (int i = 100000; i <= 200000; i++) {
        int divisors = 1;
        int x = i;
        int limit = sqrt(i);

        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 2; j <= limit; j++) {
            int count = 0;
            while (x % j == 0) {
                count++;
                x /= j;
                limit = sqrt(x);
            }
            divisors *= count + 1;
            if (j > 2)
                ++j;
        }
        if (x > 1)
            divisors *= 2;
        if (divisors > mostcount) {
            mostcount = divisors;
            most = i;
        }
    }
    cout << most << ", " << mostcount << endl;
    return;
}
```

If you find a list of prime numbers, you can cut that time in half:

```
static vector<int> primes = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 
    83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 
    197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 
    331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449 };

void f() {
    int mostcount = 0, most;
    for (int i = 100000; i <= 200000; i++) {
        int divisors = 1;
        int x = i;
        int limit = sqrt(i);

        for (int j: primes) {
            if (j > limit) break;
            int count = 0;
            while (x % j == 0) {
                count++;
                x /= j;
            }
            limit = sqrt(x);
            divisors *= count + 1;
        }
        if(x > 1) 
            divisors *= 2;
        if (divisors > mostcount) {
            mostcount = divisors;
            most = i;
        }
    }
    cout << most << ", " << mostcount << endl;
    return;
}
```

**Explanation**: let's take 166320. It's prime factors are:

- 2 (4 times)
- 3 (3 times)
- 5 (once)
- 7 (once)
- 11 (once)

Here, `2` produces 5 combination (it may go into the divisor 0 to 4 times), `3` - 3 combinations, and so on.

So you get 5 * 4 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 160 divisors. Strictly speaking, you should add one more - the input number itself.